# Getting a SecurityException in a BroadcastReceiver while accesing WifiInfo

Tags: java, android, permissions, broadcastreceiver

I'm getting a SecurityException in a BroadcastRecevier:

```
02-08 12:18:39.169 E/AndroidRuntime(22363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver surin.de.wakeonlan.BackgroudReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10171 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.

02-08 12:18:39.169 E/AndroidRuntime(22363): at surin.de.wakeonlan.BackgroudReceiver.onReceive(BackgroudReceiver.java:26)
```

My BackgroundReceiver Class:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo(); //line 26
      String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

The Receiver is registered here in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="surin.de.wakeonlan.BackgroudReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is also in the Manifest inside the Application Tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And make sure the `<uses-permission` is a direct child of the manifest-Tag and not application tag

Comment: thanks. The problem was that the uses-permission tag was in the application tag and not direct in the manifest tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add below 2 permissions (and keep `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` )

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Clean and then Build project